# Rails authenticity from Android API with HttpPost

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, rest, authentication, http-post

I'm working on an Android client API for my organization's new website. The new website is written in Rails, and authentication is done as follows: I make a POST request to the site's login URL with the credentials, and I'm returned a CSRF token and a cookie to Android's cookie manager. I then pass the CSRF token to authenticated functions.

My problem is with an UploadCSV function that I'm trying to implement. I've mimicked the request that the website's UI generates when you click the Upload CSV button, but the site is refusing my request and telling me it can't verify my CSRF token. This same token will work for other authenticated functions, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here's my function that creates the request:

```
URI url = new URI(baseURL+"/projects/"+projectId+"/CSVUpload");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,null,Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8));
entity.addPart("authenticity_token", new StringBody(authToken));
entity.addPart("csv", new FileBody(csvToUpload));
entity.addPart("utf8", new StringBody("\u2713", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
client.execute(httpPost);
```

and here is the server log message:

```
Started POST "/projects/7/CSVUpload" for ***.**.***.** at 2013-08-13 08:38:13 -0400
Processing by DataSetsController#uploadCSV as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"OvJanht9/GZu90rcRrR3YH94M8Ukamr5OLp/qiOEZAY=", "csv"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd6ae12a7a0 @original_filename="weird.csv", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"csv\"; filename=\"weird.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/9q/v5l53m3141d4cbrd8w07g0sm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130813-55943-5v1kp8>>, "utf8"=>"✓", "id"=>"7"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://***.**.**.**:3000/
Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Other functions in my API use the HTTPUrlConnection method to send their POST requests, and these authenticate fine. I want to use HttpPost to send the MultipartEntity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is not to use HttpPost. I changed my request to use an HttpURLConnection and it succeeded.

```
URL url = new URL(baseURL+"/projects/"+projectId+"/CSVUpload?authenticity_token="+URLEncoder.encode(authToken, "UTF-8"));
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("utf8", new StringBody("\u2713", "text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
entity.addPart("csv", new FileBody(csvToUpload, "text/csv"));

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", entity.getContentType().getValue());
OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
try {
    entity.writeTo(out);
} finally {
    out.close();
}
connection.getResponseCode();
```

It's a little less concise, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the token in the header `X-CSRF-Token`? I am guessing the reason some of your requests don't complain is because they use `GET`, which skips the verification.

If you want to bypass this for a `POST` as well, you can add a `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`, though I mention this with the caveat that it is not recommended.

Comment: Sorry for previous comments, I misunderstood. I just tried passing my token as with the X-CSRF-Token HTTP header, but that didn't make a difference.